# How to use continuation tokens in azure table Using Rest API

Tags: c#, rest, azure-storage

Iam using .net Azure storage client library to retrieve data from server.

My Entity contains more than 10000 records & it is retrieving 1000 records at once & giving response Headers x-ms-continuation-NextPartitionKey  & x-ms-continuation-NextRowKey

I referred this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Query-Entities?redirectedfrom=MSDN]

But did not understand how to use the those headers next time to get continuous records using Rest API

```
string storageAccount = "MyAccount";
string accessKey = "MYAccessKey";
string TableName = "TableName";
string uri = @"https://" + storageAccount + ".table.core.windows.net/" + TableName  + "?$top=100";
// Web request 
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Accept = "application/json;odata=nometadata";
request.Headers["x-ms-date"] = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
request.Headers["x-ms-version"] = "2015-04-05";           
string stringToSign = request.Headers["x-ms-date"] + "\n";    
stringToSign += "/" + storageAccount + "/" + TableName;
System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 hasher = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(accessKey));
string strAuthorization = "SharedKeyLite " + storageAccount + ":" + System.Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));


request.Headers["Authorization"] = strAuthorization;

Task<WebResponse> response = request.GetResponseAsync();
HttpWebResponse responseresult = (HttpWebResponse)response.Result;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue in query, use original query, but add parameters to request - not to headers, to query:

```
http://account.table....?query...&NextPartitionKey={value from x-ms-continuation-NextPartitionKey response header}&NextRowKey={value from x-ms-continuation-NextRowKey response header}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're really doing it the hard way, I mean, are you sure you want to manually write all requests? Looks very error prone to me. With the [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) NuGet Package, you get many function which wrap this for you. Using the Continuation Token is easy there:

Example copied from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs#list-blobs-in-pages-asynchronously):

```
//List blobs to the console window, with paging.
Console.WriteLine("List blobs in pages:");

int i = 0;
BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
BlobResultSegment resultSegment = null;

//Call ListBlobsSegmentedAsync and enumerate the result segment returned, while the continuation token is non-null.
//When the continuation token is null, the last page has been returned and execution can exit the loop.
do
{
    //This overload allows control of the page size. You can return all remaining results by passing null for the maxResults parameter,
    //or by calling a different overload.
    resultSegment = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync("", true, BlobListingDetails.All, 10, continuationToken, null, null);
    if (resultSegment.Results.Count<IListBlobItem>() > 0) { Console.WriteLine("Page {0}:", ++i); }
    foreach (var blobItem in resultSegment.Results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", blobItem.StorageUri.PrimaryUri);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    //Get the continuation token.
    continuationToken = resultSegment.ContinuationToken;
}
while (continuationToken != null);
```

We made great experience with those Microsoft NuGet Packages and highly recommend to use them.

Comment: Like this i tried, it is working fine but need to do same thing using rest API Calls

Comment: According to Documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-timeout-and-pagination you should be able to read the Keys from the Header and just pass them as the URL parameter (See **Sample Response Headers and Subsequent Request**)

Comment: Also, as a next hint... the NuGet Library is internally using the REST API. If something works as expected using the Library, you might want to monitor the HTTP Requests with a Tool like_Fiddler_. You should be able to inspect the subsequent calls and get the idea how they're structured

Comment: @thmshd it looks like the OP asked specifically for Rest API

Comment: @MuhammadMamoorKhan he/she surely did. So my answer was more a comment but too big to fit in the comments field. Sometimes people are not aware of API wrappers. Thanks.